# Dynamic html attribute naming

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a list of banking transactions that I'm listing. I'm currently using bootstrap for my HTML/CSS. I found some template code that works well enough for what I want to do, but I've run into a problem: there's no way to know the id of the collapsing div element for the parent element. It's easier to see the html than to explain:

```
{% for key, value in transactions.items %}
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading-1">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#whatid" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="whatid">
              {{ key }}
            </a>
          </h5>
        </div>

          {% for key2, value2 in value.items %}
        <div id="whatid" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
          <div class="card-body">

            <div id="accordion-1">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="heading-1-1">
                  <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-1-1">
                      {{ key2 }}
                    </a>
                  </h5>
                </div>

                  {% for tr in value2 %}
                  <div id="collapse-1-1">{{ tr.description }}</div>
                  {% endfor %}

              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The attributes `href`, `id` and most importantly `aria-controls` of the child div element can't be known ahead of time and therefore won't be correctly associated with the button click. Is it possible to do this? It's a bit of a chicken before the egg problem, so I don't really know what there is to do.

Comment: The solution will entirely depends on when your code knows that these particular divs should be collapsed. If at the time of preparing `transactions.items` you can figure out what divs should be collapsed then one extra attribute can be added like `is_collapsed` in the collection. Then in HTML for every iteration it can be checked and accordingly divs can be collapsed.

Comment: The problem isn't so much it being expanded or collapsed, it's the element that is associated with the a tag. There's not really any simple way to know what the id of the child element is to assign to aria-controls

Comment: one of the solution is to generate the div ids also dynamically using for loop and assign the same to button click event like `<div id="collapse-{{tr.someid-tr.anotherid}}">`

Comment: That was a thought I had, but the first a tag (`<a>{{ key }}</a>`) won't have access to any dynamically generated ids inside the first for loop because it's outside of it. And I don't believe there's any way to move the for loop

Comment: This requires modification in your for data structure that you looping through. If it is known in advance that this id should be associated with the button click then `value2` can have another dict which has `key3` as the div id that should be associated with button click and `value3` can have the list of `descriptions`

Comment: Looks like you need to restructure `transactions.items` and `value.items` to be in one dataset.